# How is it possible to add values to a JSON array in Javascript/angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have these initialized in my file, which is in an angular app:

```
  names = ['A','B','C','D'];

  const score = [{}];
```

After doing some processing which is working to check the current player, I want to create an array for each player. Each player's array gets added individually. First player A, then B, and so on until the last player in the names array gets called, as they are getting scores from another page.
So, like this:

```
 {
  "A":{
       "End#1":{"arrow1": "here the score",
              "arrow2": "here the score",
              "arrow3": "here the score"
             }
      },
  "B":{
       "End#1":{"arrow1": "here the score",
              "arrow2": "here the score",
              "arrow3": "here the score"
             }
      },
  "C":{
       "End#1":{"arrow1": "here the score",
              "arrow2": "here the score",
              "arrow3": "here the score"
             }
      },
  "D":{
       "End#1":{"arrow1": "here the score",
              "arrow2": "here the score",
              "arrow3": "here the score"
             }
      }
  }
```

How can I create something like this JSON array on the fly, so that I can increase and decrease it, depending on the number of names? Also, how is it possible to say that name "A" will have a second end later how can I then enter the second end?

this is the whole angular file where it sould get implemented... ( https://codepen.io/ArcherMArk/pen/ZVJwyQ ), hope this file helps a bit

Comment: Can you first fix the array? The array of objects Syntax is not correct.

Comment: array.push and JSON.parse should do the work

Comment: what would be the correct syntax? im new to json and saw people doing the syntax like this onlie somewhere :/ @JaromandaX

Comment: @JaromandaX is that now vailid?

Comment: @JaromandaX OK i hope my syntax is better now ;) how is it possible to create such an array as this was a array i have created in my mind they way it should looklike. i dont know how to add the values for each arrow into the right field for the right name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>If I understand your question correctly, the syntax for your JSON object should be something like this:</s>

**Edit:** from the extra link given in comments, it seems you don't need a  JSON object at all, just an array. Edited to reflect that.

```
scores: [
    {
        id: "A",
        endScores: {
            "End#1" : [arrowScore1, arrowScore2, arrowScore3],
            "End#2" : [arrowScore1, arrowScore2, arrowScore3]
        },
    },
    {
        id: "B",
        endScores: {
            "End#1" : [arrowScore1, arrowScore2, arrowScore3],
            "End#2" : [arrowScore1, arrowScore2, arrowScore3]
        },
    },
    {
        id: "C",
        endScores: {
            "End#1" : [arrowScore1, arrowScore2, arrowScore3],
            "End#2" : [arrowScore1, arrowScore2, arrowScore3]
        },
    },

    ...

]
```

You would then just do

```
for (var i = 0, i < scores.length; i++ ) {
    if (scores[i].id === "A") {
        scores[i].endScores["End#3"] = [newArrowScore1, newArrowScore2, newArrowScore3];
    }
}
```

Just a note - you wouldn't be adding any new entries to an array, you're just adding a new array to an object, with "End#n" as the key.

Remember, if you're setting 'scores' as a property of an object/class and referring to it in a function within that class, then you should use `this.scores`.

Comment: Yeah this looks like what i am trying to do. tho my programm is written in angular and i dont know how to get the values into an array. now i know how they arrays should look like...

Comment: shpouldn't there be a comma after the line "End#1" ?? or am i mistaken?

Comment: Yes, edited. This is in pure JavaScript. Nothing is written in Angular, Angular is written in TypeScript. If you don't know how to convert this to work in Angular, I suggest you learn the basics of JavaScript and TypeScript before attempting to learn Angular.

Comment: this line: "var obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);" where do u use the obj? for me it is coming up as unused local variable... should this work with angular?

Comment: @ArcherMark well spotted, fixed the error! It should be used in the next line instead of `jsonObj`

Comment: i have changed this in my code thos im getting this error in the console (ScoringComponent.html:124 ERROR ReferenceError: jsonObj is not defined
    at ScoringComponent.push../src/app/scoring/scoring.component.ts.ScoringComponent.setValue )

Comment: maybe this link helps u to see the whole file https://codepen.io/ArcherMArk/pen/ZVJwyQ

Comment: As I suspected, you don't need a JSON object at all in this instance. I've given the code you need to get this done, but you need to learn the basics of TypeScript and Javascript objects and classes if you want to get much further. Hint: try `this.jsonObject` instead

Comment: thank you verry much for you're help. do u have some good links or places where i can learn these skills? ;)

Comment: For JavaScript, you can try https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript and for TypeScript, try here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html

Answer (score 0):

First define json object as below
Var jobj={A:[], B:[], C:[], D:[], E:[] } ;

Var resObj={End#1:["arrow1": "here the score",
              "arrow2": "here the score",
              "arrow3": "here the score"
             ]} ;

jobj. A. push(resObj) :
jobj. B. push(resObj) :
jobj. C. push(resObj) :
jobj. D. push(resObj) :
jobj. E. push(resObj) :

By above pattern you can insert records also you can put above statment for push records to loop to make it dynamic.

Comment: jobj. A. push(resObj) ; jobj. B. push(resObj) ;jobj. C. push(resObj) ; jobj. D. push(resObj) ;jobj. E. push(resObj) ; please correct : with ;